# mlt double tent fade in and fade out

Tags: blur, fadeout, mlt

Yesterday I saw the wonderfull screen transition effect of a samsung smartphone, where the fade out and fade in was not just all screen getting black and coming back, butthe black color is arriving troug h2 lateral "tents" that arriving are making the screen black and the opposite. How to do it with melt?
PS.
the tents are blur and not just black blocks coming to blacking all the screen.

Answer (score 0):

MLT has a transitions module named "[luma](https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/TransitionLuma/)" that takes a grayscale image to define the reveal of the second image or clip. There are some examples in [this video](https://youtu.be/t1KV6gy92i0).

Most of those examples are hard edge, but there is also a softness parameter. As for the blur, you can attach a [blur filter](https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterBoxblur/) to either clips and/or the transition as well. In addition, the blurriness parameter can be animated over time.